# IBOutlet nil after refreshing data

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform, iboutlet

I'm using XCode 6.3.1 and I'm facing a weird problem that I can't figure it out.

I have a View Controller on my Storyboard opened with a modal segue. When the ViewController is opened it loads some data from my backend (Parse) it looks first on the cache and shows cached data (if exists) while the updated data from server is retrieved on the background. The process is the next:

1. Get cached data
2. If cached data exists then update interface
3. Request server data (In background)
4. When data arrives update interface

Everything works fine until step 4. When I try to refresh my interface suddenly half of my `@IBOutlets` are `nil` and of course app crashes.

what am I missing??

Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //eventId is set when the ViewController is instantiated
    if eventId != nil {
        loadEvent(eventId)
    }
}

func loadEvent(id: String) {

    var query = Event.query()
    query?.cachePolicy = Util.getCachePolicy()   //First look in cache, the request network data
    query?.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id, block: { (event: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var updatedEvent = event as! Event
            self.event = updatedEvent
            self.updateLayout()    
            //When self.updateLayout() is called with cached data 
            //all my IBOutlets are fine but when it's called the second time,
            //with data from server half of the IBOutlets are nil
        }
    })
}

func updateLayout() {

    if event != nil {

        eventTitle.text = event.name

        var paletteColor : UIColor!
        var location = event.location
        var locationName = location["name"] as! String
        eventLocation.text = NSString(format: NSLocalizedString("event_subtitle", comment: ""), event.formattedTimes(), locationName) as String

        eventDescription.text = event.abstract

        if event.paletteColor != 0 {
            paletteColor = Util.colorFromInt(event.paletteColor)
            eventHeader.backgroundColor = paletteColor
            speakersBlockTitle.textColor = paletteColor  
            mapButton.tintColor = paletteColor
        }

        if event.hasPhoto() {

            self.eventPhoto.file = event.eventPhoto
            self.eventPhoto.loadInBackground({ (image:UIImage?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                    self.eventPhoto.alpha = 1.0
                })
            })

        } else {
            self.eventPhoto.removeFromSuperview()
            if paletteColor == nil {
                paletteColor = eventHeader.backgroundColor
            }
            actionBar.backgroundColor = paletteColor
        }

        if event.speaker.isDataAvailable() {

            var speaker = event.speaker
            speakerName.text = speaker["name"] as? String
            speakerInfo.text = speaker["speakerInfo"] as? String
            speaker["speakerPhoto"]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.speakerPhoto.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    self.speakerPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = self.speakerPhoto.frame.size.width/2
                    self.speakerPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
                }
            })
        } else {
            speakerBlock.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.eventHeader.alpha = 1.0
            self.eventDescription.alpha = 1.0
            self.speakerBlock.alpha = 1.0
            self.mapButton.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

This are all the nil IBOutlets:
[image: This are all the nil IBOutlets:]

Comment: It sounds like those outlets are being deallocated under your feet. Are they in a separate view controller that you're not holding a strong reference to somehow? Anyhow, my best suggestion is to declare a property observer (say, `didSet`) on those outlets and place a breakpoint there to find out when and why they're being set to `nil`.

Comment: Something like this:

`@IBOutlet weak var myOutlet: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            if myOutlet == nil {
                // put a breakpoint on the next line
                println("myOutlet set to nil")
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: I'll try it. the `IBOutlets`are on the same view controller btw

Answer (score 0):

Since the code in my comment above doesn't display correctly, here's that comment again:

Something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myOutlet: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        if myOutlet == nil {
            // put a breakpoint on the next line
            println("myOutlet set to nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good advice, but it was fine as a comment.  pasting it into a code editor would cause good-enough formatting.

Comment: So, I tried it:     @IBOutlet weak var speakersBlockTitle: CustomUILabel! {
        didSet {
            if speakersBlockTitle == nil {
                // put a breakpoint on the next line
                println("myOutlet set to nil")
            }
        }
    } 

But no luck, the app crashes without even noticing the breakpoint

Comment: Is that the only outlet that's being set to `nil`? If not, you should set a property observer on every one of them. What does the stack trace say?

Comment: I just did. The stack trace say "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and I did set observers on all of my IBOutlets that are nil, but none of them was fired before the crash

Comment: Also, I've noticed the `IBOutlets` only are nil when they don't have a value assigned. When the information is complete they are always fine, but if something is missing then I guess they get deallocated but how can I prevent the system to deallocate them?

Comment: Here's at least one problem I see in your code. When there's no speaker data available you remove `speakerBlock` from its superview. But then you animate its alpha value. Now, it's quite possible that when you remove `speakerBlock` from its superview it gets deallocated (because I bet you have it declared as a `weak` outlet)  so when it's time to set its alpha, boom, the app crashes because it's trying to dereference a nil reference. I haven't checked but it's possible your other outlets have a similar problem.

Comment: Declaring those outlet properties as `strong` would ensure that the view controller keeps a reference to them alive even when nothing else in your code is doing that. That will probably solve your problem. Something else I think you should consider is to be extra careful with all the background loading you're doing from within the UI update. What if the user moves to a different view controller? Then your bg activity, when done, will be trying to update a UI that may no longer be in place. The app will crash again in that scenario.

Comment: Man that is the problem! Thanks a lot. Any idea on how can I hide the unused IBOutlets without removing them? the property hidden doesn't work because even when they are invisible they still use space on the screen

Comment: You can still remove them from their superviews but you need to make sure that the view controller keeps them around so simply declare `@IBOutlet var speakerBlock: UIView!` instead of `@IBOutlet weak var speakerBlock: UIView!`.  Note the absence of `weak`. That makes the property a `strong` one. If you want, for clarity, you can even add the `strong` keyword in place of the `weak` one. Also, add a comment to your code explaining why you need them to be `strong` so neither you nor a co-worker accidentally changes it back to `weak` 6 months from now when no one remembers what happened. :)

Comment: Do I have to add something else to release that memory when the ViewController is closed?